# Symfony 3: How to sync users using Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I wanted to know how to sync users for example on my user table (fos_user) I want to sync username with another tables.

So if I want to see who is the user that posted a comment I want to do

> $commentA->getUser();

and it will show the user of the user table (fos_user), for that when the user change his username the comment will get his new username.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are database relationships - OneToMany / ManyToOne in doctrine - See in documentation - https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Then you use your primary key as connecting key, not username.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this,

In your `User` class you need this `property` and `methods`:

```
/**
 * Class User
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends FosUser
{
    [Your other properties]

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $comments;

        /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

        /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    /**
     * @param Comment $comment
     */
    public function addComment(Comment $comment): void
    {
        if ($this->getComments()->contains($comment)) {

            return;
        } else {

            $this->getComments()->add($comment);
            $comment->setUser($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Comment $comment
     */
    public function removeComment(Comment $comment): void
    {
        if (!$this->getComments()->contains($comment)) {

            return;
        } else {

            $this->getComments()->removeComment($comment);
            $comment->setUser(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `Comment` class you need this `property` and `methods`:

```
/**
 * Class User
 * @ORM\Table(name="`comment`")
 */
class Comment
{
    [Your other properties]
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser(): User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser(User $user): void
    {
        /** Maybe you need this too, if get exception delete this line */
        $user->addComment($this);
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Maybe you need `cascade={"persist"}` in your annotation in User class or Comment class ... depend on your logic.

something like this line

```
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="user", cascade{"persist"})
```

now your comments connected to owner user, and if user change, commit user change too, and you must use class user like this way:

```
$comment->getUser()->getUsername();
```